# How to extend objects contained in a List?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a List named resourceItems which containes ResourceItem objects.

```
    public class ResourceItem {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        public ResourceItem(Long id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
        // getters and setters...
    }

    public class SomeClass {
        private List<ResourceItem>  resourceItems = FindAllResourcesWebSerbice();
    }
```

I would like to extend the objects in the List to include a boolean field named selected.

I've tried several variations of classes that extends ResourceItem (see below) including options using generics, but have not been successful.  I would love a solution that uses generics for reuse.

```
    public class ExtendedResourceItem extends ResourceItem {
        private boolean selected = false;
        public ExtendedResourceItem() {
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass {
        private List<ResourceItem>  resourceItems = FindAllResourcesWebSerbice();
        private List<ExtendedResourceItem> extendedResourceItem = resourceItems;
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like a `Map<ResourceItem, Boolean>` might answer your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ResourceItem` implements `equals` and `hashCode` correctly, why not just keep a set of the ones that are selected:

```
Set<ResourceItem> selectedResourceItems = new HashSet<ResourceItem>();
```

Then you could [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) an item to the set when it's selected, [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) it when it's deselected, and check to see if the set [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) one when you need to know if it's selected.

This solution is very similar to [Michael Myers' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381774/how-to-extend-objects-contained-in-a-list/13382114#comment18274953_13381774) about using a `Map<ResourceItem, Boolean>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use composition, not inheritance here. From your description it sounds like `ResourceItem` is a domain object, but on screen, you should wrap it

```
class ScreenResourceItem {
    ResourceItem item;
    boolean selected;
}
```

Create a new list of `ScreenResourceItem` and put all the wrapped `ResourceItem`s in it.

Generics and list covariance are not relevant here.

Comment: This sounds promising.  I'll implement and see how it goes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

But using your snippet:

```
private List<ResourceItem> resourceItems = ... \\ some assignment;
private List<ExtendedResourceItem> extendedResourceItems = resourceItems;
```

is absolutely wrong. Since not any ResourceItem is guarantee to be also ExtendedResourceItem. (resourceItems list can contain objects that are ResourceItem but are NOT ExtendedResourceItem).

I don't see the point you want to reach, but if You want to transform resourceItems into list of resourceItems that have `selected` attribute, what about this concept:

```
public class ExtendedResourceItem {
    private ResourceItem item = null;
    private boolean selected = false;

    public ExtendedResourceItem(ResourceItem item, boolean selected) {
        this.item = item;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    // ... getters and setters
}

public class SomeClass {
    private List<ResourceItem> resourceItems = FindAllResourcesWebSerbice();

    private List<ExtendedResourceItem> extendedResourceItems = new ArrayList<ExtendedResourceItem>();
    for (ResourceItem item: resourceItems) {
        extendedResourceItems.add(new ExtendedResourceItem(item, false));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and good point as I have a map solution that worked, but I wanted to explore the extends option.

Comment: I have just implemented this option in my solution.  Works and very readable / maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the generics limits that are confusing? Try using the [Upper Bounded Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html), e.g.

```
public class SomeClass {
    private List<ExtendedResourceItem> extendedResourceItems = FindAllResourcesWebSerbice();
    private List<? extends ResourceItem> resourceItems = extendedResourceItems;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private List<? extends ExtendedResourceItem> extendedResourceItems = FindAllResourcesWebSerbice();
    private List<? extends ResourceItem> resourceItems = extendedResourceItems;
}
```

More information about wildcards [Wildcards and Subtyping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html).